# slim/twig-view Won't Work With Additional Route Middleware

Tags: php, twig, slim-4

I've been using slim/twig-view, documented here: https://notes.enovision.net/slim/composer-package-documentation/slim_twig-view. The recommended way to handle a route, render a view is:

```
$app->get('/hello/{name}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    $view = Twig::fromRequest($request);
    return $view->render($response, 'profile.html', [
        'name' => $args['name']
    ]);
})
```

Problem is, if you try to add any route based middleware to run afterwards, it fails

```
$app->get('/hello/{name}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    $view = Twig::fromRequest($request);
    return $view->render($response, 'profile.html', [
        'name' => $args['name']
    ]);
})->add(function(Request $request, RequestHandler $handler){
    $response = $handler->handle($request);
    return $response;
});
```

With an error like this:

```
Type: TypeError
Code: 0
Message: Return value of Slim\Handlers\Strategies\RequestResponse::__invoke() must implement interface Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface, int returned
File: /var/www/html/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Handlers/Strategies/RequestResponse.php
Line: 43
```

I see this is because I'm not returning a response from the route handler, so I rewrite the route handler to return the $response:

```
 $view = Twig::fromRequest($request);
    $view->render($response, 'profile.html', [
        'name' => $args['name']
    ]);
    return $response;
```

Still the same error.

I can work around this, but it's a greenfield project and it would be nice to have access to route middleware. Any ideas?

Comment: Mhm, usually on Symfony you `return $view->render(...)` this is also what they do on the doc page you are linking

Comment: Seems to be true here too: `public function render(ResponseInterface $response, string $template, array $data = []): ResponseInterface` https://github.com/slimphp/Twig-View/blob/94bcc75e8044d0072e29b149f1be4967c12d0c1d/src/Twig.php#L200

Comment: Do you have the same issue if you just do not chain the two? e.g. `$app->get(...); $app->add(...);`

Comment: It's only when I chain.

Comment: I like the way twig is used in here https://odan.github.io/2020/04/17/slim4-twig-templates.html

Comment: I copied the example from the link in your question in `index.php`, removed all its route definitions, added your route definition for `/hello/{name}` **with route middleware** and it just shows the expected result. Please provide more details, if possible, a full example would help a lot (i.e not only the route definition , but a simple full app like the link you provided)